# A simple framework for Google App Engine (like Sinatra)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-frameworks

Is there a simple 'wrapper' framework for appengine? Something like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) or [Juno](http://github.com/breily/juno)? So that one can write code like the following:

```
from juno import *

@route('/')
def index(web):
    return 'Juno says hi'

run()
```

**UPDATE**: I want to use the Python API (not Java) in GAE.

Comment: Funny. I was thinking I wanted something like that, just yesterday. Getting sick of running backwards and forwards between urls.py (in django) or the yaml file in GAE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several frameworks either specifically for App Engine, or well suited to it:

- [web.py](http://webpy.org/) - Not specifically for App Engine, but well suited.
- [Google App Engine Oil](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-oil/)
- [web2py](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/) - Also not specifically for App Engine
- [pyxer](http://code.google.com/p/pyxer/)
- [kay](http://code.google.com/p/kay-framework/)
- [tipfy](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/)

Comment: Thanks. A quick look at the mentioned frameworks suggests that `kay` is something I'd like better than the others. I will spend some time with `kay` and report my thoughts on it later.

Answer (score 2):

No such framework has been released at this time, to the best of my knowledge (most people appear to be quite happy with Django I guess;-).  You could try using Juno with [this patch](http://gist.github.com/140565) -- it doesn't seem to be quite ready for prime time, but then again, it IS a pretty tiny patch, maybe little more is needed to allow Juno to work entirely on GAE!

Comment: Yea, I already looked at this patch before .. it disables templates/ORM resulting in a pretty useless framework.

Comment: @Sridhar, obviously you can't have ORMs in GAE since there's no R (GAE's storage is non-relational), and the templates available are only those you can do in pure Python (django being most popular, though I still like my ancient YAPTU;-), not jinja or others needing C-coded extensions.  To use App Engine effectively, you must accept its limitations -- non-relational storage, and pure-Python-only extensions.

Comment: True, but at least Juno's "Person = model('Person', ...)" API could be translated to the underlying appengine models. That patch didn't cover that.

Comment: @Sridhar, yep, it's a tiny patch -- not quite ready, as I said, but close enough to "need little more" (within what _can_ be done on GAE of course) -- only the Juno maintainers know their plans for sure, but one or two volunteers to help on this might make all the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I use [web.py](http://webpy.org/). It's really simple and doesn't get in your way.

This is how it looks:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'world'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another framework that I've been meaning to try out is [Bloog](http://bloog.billkatz.com/). It is actually a blog engine for GAE but also provides a framework for developing other GAE apps.

Answer (score 1):

[Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/index.html) is one-single-file framework, so it's very easy to deploy it on GAE.

Bottle is similar with Sinatra, see the "hello world" example below:

Sinatra:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Bottle:

```
from bottle import *
@get('/hi')
    def hi():
        return "Hello World!"
```

Though I have to admit that Ruby is better for DSL.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [gaelyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/).  It's a lightweight framework on top of appengine that uses groovy.

Comment: But that is for the Java API; I need one for the Python API.